# Started or was started

Tags: grammar

Just wanted to know which of these is grammatically correct?
Project implementation started
Project implementation was started

Comment: It would be useful if you gave the full sentence where these words are going to be used.

Comment: *Has started* may be better, but it does depend on the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> Project implementation started

Here `Project implementation` is the subject and when you complete the sentence like `Project implementation started yesterday`, that means `Project implementation` does something (here `started`).

> Project implementation was started

This is in passive voice. and `Project implementation` is object here. When you complete the sentence like `Project implementation was started yesterday` it means someone started the `Project implementation`.

So the correct one is

> **Project implementation was started**

Comment: Thanks everyone. It is all clear now.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please upvote the answer and mark as correct. Thanks in advanced.